# Selecting the Default profile on Microsoft Edge with Selenium (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```js
import { Builder } from 'selenium-webdriver'
import edge from 'selenium-webdriver/edge'

export async function getBrowserDriver() {
  const browser = 'MicrosoftEdge'

  const edgeOptions = new edge.Options()
  edgeOptions.addArguments(`--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\bruno\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data\\`)
  edgeOptions.addArguments('--profile-directory=Default')
  edgeOptions.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  edgeOptions.addArguments('--no-sandbox')
  // edgeOptions.addArguments('--disable-dev-tools')
  // edgeOptions.addArguments('--remote-debugging-port=9222')


  return new Builder()
    .forBrowser(browser)
    .setEdgeOptions(edgeOptions)
    .build()
}
```

This works if I swap everything to use Chrome, everything just works. However, when I try the exact same using Edge I run into this error:

```
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Microsoft Edge failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\BrunoLM\Projects\x\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:524:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\BrunoLM\Projects\x\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:601:13)
    at Executor.execute (C:\BrunoLM\Projects\x\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:529:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I have seen suggestions to use `--disable-dev-shm-usage` and also `--no-sandbox`, AI even suggested `--disable-dev-tools`. Nothing works. I've tried a few combinations and I either get this error or an error saying that it couldn't even reach chrome.

AI also suggested I installed `npm install -g webdriver-manager` and ran `webdriver-manager update`. I've tried that too, but it made no difference.

I downloaded the msedgedriver.exe and I think I was able to hook it up with selenium with

```js
    const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge')
    .usingServer('http://localhost:9515').setEdgeOptions(edgeOptions).build()

    return driver
```

I did see some logs:

```
Starting Microsoft Edge WebDriver 119.0.2151.44 (x) on port 9515
To submit feedback, report a bug, or suggest new features, please visit https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver

Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://aka.ms/WebDriverSecurity for suggestions on keeping Microsoft Edge WebDriver safe.

Microsoft Edge WebDriver was started successfully.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
Opening in existing browser session.
```

But it doesn't matter what I try it ends up in:

```
DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

It opens a browser window, but it crashes, and I have the window open but can't access it at all.

**Am I doing something wrong or is it an issue with the driver or Edge? Is there any way to fix it? Maybe downgrade something?**

Comment: This one should solve your issue; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76818666/i-am-getting-unknown-error-in-python-while-useing-selenium

Comment: @OnurBaysal I think that person ran in the exact same situation I did. But the answers there are wrong, doing what they suggest creates an empty profile which is not at all what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did not create a profile, but just kill all msedge.exe. Like in the second suggestion. "taskkill /f /im msedge.exe"
It did work for me. I think there is an issue with ms edge. If you already running the current profile, it does not allow you to login as that profile.